# Temporary table that calculates SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I am trying to figure out how to make two temporary tables, one of them should calculate every book's copy price sum, and the other one should calculate every copy's average sum.

**Task:** "Find the titles of books for which the total value of all copies is lower than the average total value of copies for all books. If the value of a book is not specified, consider it to be equal to 15."

I know that there is a better way to do my task, but I am doing this for learning purpose.

I am testing the SUM and AVERAGE with this code:

```
WITH CopiesSum AS (
        SELECT  SUM(COALESCE(book.cost, 15)) AS total_sum
        FROM    copy, book
        WHERE   book.ISBN = copy.ISBN
        GROUP BY copyISBN
),
AveragePrice AS (
        SELECT  AVG(COALESCE(book.cost, 15)) AS average_price
        FROM    book, copy
        WHERE   book.ISBN = copy.ISBN
)
SELECT book.title, total_sum, average_price
FROM    book, CopiesSum, AveragePrice
GROUP BY book.title, AveragePrice.average_price, CopiesSum.total_sum;
```

With this code I get 49 lines instead of 7 lines (there is only 7 books in DB). The average price that I am getting is correct, but I get way too many sums. For every book, I get every sum. Like this:

```
Book1 | avg | sum_of_book_1_copies
Book1 | avg | sum_of_book_2_copies
Book2 | avg | sum_of_book_1_copies
Book2 | avg | sum_of_book_2_copies
```

The correct answer should look like this:

```
Book1 | avg | sum_of_book_1_copies
Book2 | avg | sum_of_book_2_copies
```

This is my DB scheme
[image: DB Scheme]

**EDIT:** I think I figured it out. I will just show you my code.

```
WITH CopiesSum AS (
        SELECT  book.title,
                SUM(COALESCE(book.cost, 15)) AS total_sum
        FROM    copy
        JOIN    book ON book.ISBN = copy.ISBN
        GROUP BY book.title
),
VidutinesVertes AS (
        SELECT  AVG(COALESCE(book.cost, 15)) AS average_price
        FROM    book
        JOIN    copy ON knyga.isbn = copy.ISBN
)
SELECT  title, total_sum, average_price
FROM    CopiesSum
JOIN    AveragePrice ON 1 = 1;
```

I am just not sure if `1 = 1` is a good practice.

Comment: `GROUP BY` but no aggregate functions? Are you simply trying to do `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh I want the output to be kind of like ```DISTINCT```, that every book would have their own copies sum. Now I get one book with a lot of sums.

Comment: `1 = 1` is an odd choice. Check out `CROSS JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

you can give a try to this:

```
WITH CopiesSum AS (
    SELECT 
        book.ISBN,
        COALESCE(SUM(copy.cost), 15) AS total_sum
    FROM
        book
    LEFT JOIN
        copy ON book.ISBN = copy.ISBN
    GROUP BY
        book.ISBN
),
AveragePrice AS (
    SELECT 
        AVG(COALESCE(book.cost, 15)) AS average_price
    FROM
        book
)
SELECT 
    book.title, 
    AveragePrice.average_price, 
    CopiesSum.total_sum
FROM
    book
LEFT JOIN
    CopiesSum ON book.ISBN = CopiesSum.ISBN
CROSS JOIN
    AveragePrice
WHERE
    CopiesSum.total_sum < AveragePrice.average_price;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).